# Add image to a column that is in first row of grid in extjs

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.1

How can i implement image in a single row only that is in grid and i dont need image in other row since i am using that button to add row in bottom[image]

Answer (score -1):

instead of data for that particular cell, return `html img tag`

for example return :- `"<img src='../shared/icons/fam/delete.gif'></img>"` in your xml/json